Can I replace the LCD of my Nikon D3000 with the screen of a D3300?
I have an old D3000 lying around and when I turned it on it’s got dimmed corners around it. I was looking for options and I was wondering if a D3300 LCD would work with the D3000. Thanks.

Most probably not because D3300 LCD has higher resolution. There's almost no chance the firmware would detect new resolution (not all display types even transmit than information) let alone adapt to it even if it's mechanically compatible (what's also not in any way guaranteed).
